# Как ссылать на определённый фрагмент кода?

Tags: php

Есть файл `index.php`, в нём около 200 строк. Допустим, у нас в нём есть две формы и два обработчика. Нужно, чтобы одна форма обрабатывалась одним обработчиком, а другая другим. Как реализовать?

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы!Но если допустим у нас есть ссылка <a href"">Регистрация</a>, как из этой ссылки ссылаться на конкретный фрагмент кода в том же файле где эта кнопка?

Comment: Уточните: что должно произойти, когда жмут на ссылку `<a href="">Регистрация</a>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в формы по скрытому полю, чтобы идентифицировать, какую из них отправили:

```
<form name="First">
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="1" />
</form>
...
<form name="Second">
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="2" />
</form>
```

И в обработчиках смотрите переменную `$_GET['form_id']`:

```
if( isset($_GET['form_id']) {
    if( $_GET['form_id'] == 1) {
        // обработчик первой формы
    } elseif( $_GET['form_id'] == 2) {
        // обработчик второй формы
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно задавать имена кнопкам в каждой форме, к примеру

```
<input type="submit" name="form_1">
<input type="submit" name="form_2">
```

Ну а затем проверкой

```
if(!empty($_POST['form_1']))
{
   ....
}

if(!empty($_POST['form_2']))
{
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В простейшем случае - по переменной в запросе.

index.php?form_id=2&....

index.php?form_id=1&...

```
<?php
if($_REQUEST['form_id']==1){
form1_processor_function();
}

if($_REQUEST['form_id']==2){
form2_processor_function();
}
```